Зачем нужен регистр AL в NASM
Зачем нужен регистр AL и что в нём хранится?

AL - это младшие 8 битов регистра процессора AX (это не регистр NASM). Хранить там можно всё, что туда влезает, т.е. либо знаковые целые от -128 до 127, либо беззнаковые от 0 до 255.
Первоначально регистр AL (AX) был единственным регистром, который был обязателен для всех операций (сложение, вычитание, сдвиги и т.п.), и в который помещался результат операции.
